# Using Knockout, phone number not validating on Android tablets

Tags: android, validation, knockout.js, mask, phone-number

Using Knockout, phone number not validating on Android tablets.

Here is the code that we're using and it works well for desktop validation, but it fails on the few Android tablets with which we've tested.

It will not let me continue if I have a working phone number in the text field.

This was written by a more experienced developer and I'm trying to fix it, with no knockout experience.

```html
<input type="tel" maxlength="10" data-bind="value: PrimaryPhoneNumber" 
class="form-control" id="iEmployerPhone" name="iEmployerPhone" 
data-placement="bottom" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, digitsOnly);">
```

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="masked: PrimaryPhoneNumber, mask: '(999) 999-9999'" 
class="form-control" id="iEmployerPhone" name="iEmployerPhone" 
data-placement="top"
```

```js
                employerPhoneRequired: function (input) {
                    if (input.is("[name^=iEmployerPhone]")) {
                        return input.val().trim() !== "";
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                employerPhoneInvalid: function (input) {
                    var regex = !isMobile() ? /^\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3}(?:-|\s*)\d{4})$/ : /^\d{10}$/;
                    if (input.is("[name^=iEmployerPhone]")) {
                        return regex.test(input.val());
                    }
                    return true;
                },
```

Comment: It's not using Knockout for the input value, which seems like a mistake. What calls these functions?

Comment: Depending on what `isMobile` does (check whether it's a mobile device? Android?), the required format is different: `111 222-3333` vs `1112223333`

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this and it doesn't work on Android Tablets.

 <input type="tel" maxlength="10" data-bind="value: PrimaryPhoneNumber" class="form-control" id="iEmployerPhone" name="iEmployerPhone" data-placement="bottom" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(this, event, digitsOnly);">

Comment: Do you know whether `restrictCharacters` is being called? What it's finding? Is `employeePhoneInvalid` being called? Is it doing anything? Can you figure out exactly what you could remove from the code to let you continue?

Comment: restrictCharacters() is being called. It is limiting the input to use only numbers. 

<input type="tel" name="iEmployerPhone"> This is the code that is making it validate. I believe it is using the JS above, specifically var regex = !isMobile() ? /^\((\d{3})\)\s*(\d{3}(?:-|\s*)\d{4})$/ : /^\d{10}$/;